# ReferenceError: require is not defined using require("dotenv").config();

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

For some reason i am having this error "ReferenceError: require is not defined" and i cant figure out why ?. Has anyone got an idea how i can fix this ? i am trying to connect my e-commerce website to mongodb

here's the code

.env file

```
PORT=5000
MONGO_URL = mongodb+srv://nashmaj:frzw14qa@cluster0.52b6h.mongodb.net/e-commerce-webapp?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

server.js file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
// const { Console } = require('console');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors)
app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles: true
}))
//connect to db

const URL = process.env.MONGO_URL
mongoose.connect({
    useCreateIndex: true, 
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
}, err=> {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Connected to Mongo DB')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.json({msg: "Welcome"})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => { 
    console.log('Server is running on port', PORT)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if you have configured node to use ES Modules. This is in package.json

"type": "module",

Remove this line and check again.

Remember that having "type": "module"you cannot use require and instead you need to use import syntax.