# dotenv and vanilla javascript- Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, dotenv

I tried using require('dotenv').config() in my javascript file and my package.json, I have dotenv as my dependency, I am able to check my environment variable however, when it comes to loading my javascript page, it throws an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". If I remove require('dotenv').config() my page loads perfectly with javascript however, when I add require('dotenv').config() this again, it throws the subject line error. Can someone please help me with the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you run this script in the browser?

Comment: I run it in node. browser would mean client side?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752833/referenceerror-require-is-not-defined-using-requiredotenv-config

Comment: Thanks Andy, I checked this post though, I do not have type = module in .json package. Not sure, what else is causing the error :(

Comment: I think this could be relaed to this problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/74134178/2743774

Comment: similar, tried the import solution as well, doesn't work